# Why is radius of gyration for an ellipsoid derived from a tensor different than the formula?

Tags: rotation, moment-of-inertia, eigenvalue

The first method one can use to solve for radius of gyration, $R_g$, of an ellipsoid with semi-axes a, b, and c involves using the formula:
$$ R_g = \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{5}}$$
However, it appears you can also solve for radius of gyration using the gyration tensor and the principal moments of gyration $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$ (https://isg.nist.gov/deepzoomweb/measurement3Ddata_help#shape-metrics-formulas):
$$ R_g = \sqrt{R_1+R_2+R_3} $$
It is my understanding that $a=\sqrt{R_1}$, $b=\sqrt{R_2}$, and $c=\sqrt{R_3}$. If this is correct, the first method I listed has a factor of $1/\sqrt{5}$ that doesn't appear in calculation with the second method. Why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: Is one for a solid  ellipsoid  and the other a hollow one?

Comment: For a solid ellipsoid.

Comment: Recall that the moment lof inertia of a soiid sphere of radius $R$  is $I=(2/5)MR^2$.